# Streaming private videos using jwplayer and amazon cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I use JWPlayer 6.7 as a client to show an .mp4 video. The video is hosted in an S3 bucket on amazon and is only accessible through a private rtmp cloudfront distribution. This works fine for devices that  support flash (which can use RTMP), but it does not work for iOS devices that can only use HTML5 video (that does not support RTMP as I have learned).

I use the code listed below. The fallback (the second file item in the sources list) needs to be http instead of rtmp, because of the HTML5 player. The distribution I use in the example below is the same in both cases, but I guess it cannot handle the http call because it is an rtmp distribution (, right?).

So the question is: how do I set up the amazon cloudfront distributions to get this working? I would prefer to be able to use the same mp4 file in the S3 bucket and for the file to be streamed in the HTML5 player instead of downloaded (is that possible?) The video needs to be private (using a private distribution and requiring a key to see it) in both cases (rtmp and http)

Many thanks!

```
jwplayer('video').setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: '//d12q7hepqvd422.cloudfront.net/image.png',
        sources: [
            {file: 'rtmp://s3e5mnr1tue3qm.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/name&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIAS7DDQFOAHAHOTQ'},
            {file: 'http://s3e5mnr1tue3qm.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/name&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIAS7DDQFOAHAHOTQ'}
        ]
    }],
    primary: 'flash',
    flashplayer: '//d12q7hepqvd422.cloudfront.net/global/js/jwplayer6.7.4071/jwplayer.flash.swf?v=2',
    html5player: '//d12q7hepqvd422.cloudfront.net/global/js/jwplayer6.7.4071/jwplayer.htm5.js?v=2',
    width: '940',
    height: '403'
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this is running?

Comment: support [at] jwplayer [dot] com

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?